# Usage with "is" in this example

Tags: sentence-construction, british-english

A film scene **is made** all the more powerful by its score.

Can we say something is made powerful?

Should it be something like: brought to life by its powerful score.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're unsure about "made powerful"?

Comment: You are free to express yourself in any way you wish. And your sentence is both grammatical and meaningful.

Comment: Juhasz It is just the dual meanings of the word 'made'. Made in my example is referring to the emotive effect of its score, as opposed to actually making it powerful 'physically' but it could be interpreted either way..

Comment: Maybe if you insert something about the angle the power comes in. Something like "more emotionally powerful" or "more evocatively powerful" or "more powerfully persuasive" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence

> A film scene is made **all the more powerful** by its score.
>   *A film scene becomes more powerful because of its score.*

is correct and understandable. You don't have to say ***how*** it is more **powerful**.

> A film scene is ***brought to life*** by its **powerful** score
>   A film scene is ***made more meaningful*** by its **powerful** score

Just as

> A film scene is **more powerful** *with a great score.*
>   A film scene *with a great score* is **more powerful.**

They all have the same basic meaning.